# Difference between H/N, HN and H∩N

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to understand the second isomorphism theorem, and I'm kind of stuck. An example in Z would be very appreciated. :)

Comment: Do you know what a subgroup is, and what a normal subgroup is? People will be able to give you better help if you can say a little bit more about what it is that you don't understand.

Comment: Are you asking for an example in $\mathbb{Z}$ of the second isomorphism theorem? Or an example of the notation used in the question title?

Answer (score 2):

In $Z$, all subgroups are normal. Let's look at $H = 6\mathbb Z$ and $N = 8\mathbb Z$.  $H/N$ doesn't appear in the 2nd isomorphism theorem, so I won't mention that. $HN$ is the set of all sums of things in $H$ and things in $N$. Since $18 \in H$ and $16 \in N$, we have $2 \in HN$, so all even numbers are in $HN$. But everything in $HN$ is even, so $HN = 2\mathbb Z$.

What about $H \cap N$? Something that's a multiple of $6$ and $8$ must be a multiple of their least common multiple, which is $24$. So $H \cap N = 24 \mathbb Z$.

And following @MJD's comment, what is $\mathbb Z/H$? It's $\mathbb Z / 6\mathbb Z$, the cyclic group of order $6$ (i.e., clock arithmetic in a world with a 6-hour day).

Comment: You might mention $\Bbb Z/H$ though.